# Fast encoding with ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, encoding, transcoding, recommendation

I know about presets but faster presets lose the video quality. Are there any hardware requirements I need to consider? Or are there any settings that I need to tweak? And lastly where do I place the `-threads` flag to encode video (before input or after input), I saw topics on thread but they were confusing.

This is the command I am using now:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 \
            -codec:v libx264 -tune zerolatency -profile:v main -preset medium -crf 23 -maxrate 1000k -bufsize 10000k -s hd720 -codec:a libfdk_aac -pix_fmt yuv420p -movflags +faststart -threads 4 highoutput.mp4 \
            -codec:v libx264 -tune zerolatency -profile:v main -preset medium -crf 23 -maxrate 500k -bufsize 5000k -s hd480 -codec:a libfdk_aac -pix_fmt yuv420p -movflags +faststart -threads 4 lowoutput.mp4
```

Your help and guidance will be very much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Faster presets do less work to come up with the same quality if you're using Constant Rate Factor (-crf). So AFAIK the trade-off isn't less quality, but bigger files.

Comment: @stib Is there any way to maintain the bitrate?

Comment: Doesn't using `-crf` override any bitrate options on the command line? I seem to recall that being the case.

Comment: @WineSoaked Is it? I saw  this [post](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264#CRFwithmaximumbitrate) telling me otherwise.